# Call a method in a TaskService?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a Taskscheduler in my application after some time interval i want to run/call a method, after my application has started.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Open App";

    Trigger tg = Trigger.CreateTrigger(TaskTriggerType.Time);
    Trigger tri = Trigger.CreateTrigger(TaskTriggerType.Event);
}
```

I have a method like Getdata(). And I want to call this method in scheduled time(Like Daily 10:30AM).

Please help.

Comment: You want the TaskScheduler to call a method in your application? Why are you using a TaskScheduler (I think you are using this [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/)). Why dont you simply use a Timer? What happens if your application isnt running?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an open-source library such as [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler) to easily perform any action at a given time.

Just use `NuGet` to download FluentScheduler: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentScheduler/

...and try this:

```
Schedule(() => GetData()).ToRunEvery(1).Days().At(10, 30);
```